# Libgdx: transform vector2 around z-axis

Tags: java, c#, matrix, libgdx, xna

I´m trying to port a tower defence game from xna (c#) to libgdx (java).

But now I have a problem, there is a function which rotates the bullets from the towers around the z-axis in direction to the enemies.

```
public void SetRotation(float value){
    rotation = value;
    velocity = Vector2.Transform(new Vector2(0, -speed), Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation));
}
```

This is the code in c# using xna. Does anybody know how to do this in libgdx?

Here ist the link form the tutorial side from the tutorial: http://xnatd.blogspot.de/2010/10/tutorial-7-firepower.html.

I hope there is someone who can help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Vector2#rotate`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html#rotate-float-) rotate the vector around the Z axis. Note that it needs the angle in degrees. If the angle you have is in radians then use the [`rotateRad`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html#rotateRad-float-) method.

```
velocity.set(0, -speed).rotate(value);
//or
velocity.set(0, -speed).rotateRad(value);
```